# JavaScript filetree with relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, entity-relationship, filetree

I am looking for a JavaScript method or a framework to achieve this:

[image]

So in concrete words I like to have a tree structure same like the one in the Windows Explorer (where you can expand and collapse nodes) and on the right side you should be able to relate nodes to each others.

Building the tree structure is pretty simple, but displaying the relation for the nodes is quite tricky and honestly I don't know how to start.

I tried with various frameworks, but none that I know of has this build in functionallity. Unfortunately I cannot copy any code to JSFiddle...

Comment: I think this is what your looking for: jQuery TreeView: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview

Comment: unfortunately now... as said there are many tree structure frameworks out there, but non can relate different nodes to each other like on my screenshot. By the way, i used the framework that u showed as well and it works only with attribute, value... instead of pushing in DIVs

Answer (score 0):

try https://www.jstree.com/ it will help ;), or look in here http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-treeview/

Comment: same comment as for Gabriel Rodriguez, the relation on the right side is not achieveable with these framworks, I have tested them all

Comment: this offers alot! it is actually pretty close to my idea, i ll give it a try and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: unfortunately this charts works on canvas basis, so in other words you cannot interact with 'normal' html elements